# Can't expand div width

Tags: html, css

I want to expand the div to fit the whole page width but it is't working, can someone review this? **I am fairly new to HTML and CSS.**
I used the div to load another html file using js

```
function load_home()
{
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="top.html" ></object>';
}
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {width:100%;}

#header {width:100%;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header"> </div>
```

Comment: What are you wanting to put in the header? This question is EXTREMELY vague...

Comment: Add dummy text inside the header div and add a background color to your header CSS. This way, it will be easier to see the results.

Comment: html, body and div are block elements and take 100% width by default. add border to header to check if its width is 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, apparently I needed to expand the width of the object not the div. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/4mct02nn/)

html:

```
<div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
```

css:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
#header
{ 
width: 100%; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
    Color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```